# SQL Server table query with pagination performance tuning, understand the current solution

Tags: sql-server, performance-tuning, linq, pagination

as stated in the title i start a performance tuning of a table query with pagination generated by a legacy program that use Linq To SQL as ORM.

I have found this resource in which is highly recommended to sort table before pagination :
https://rimdev.io/optimizing-linq-sql-skip-take/

So i have follow the suggestion provided and experimented an huge difference. It's clear to me that is somewhat related on how row_nummber is calculated but is not clear to me exactly what happened and why there is so much difference between the two queries.

Original slow query (dataset of ~7K elements, take ~3s) :

```
SELECT [t7].[ID], [t7].[ID_BRAND], [t7].[CODE], [t7].[CODFOR], [t7].[COD_ALT01], [t7].[COD_ALT02], [t7].[COD_ALT03], [t7].[ID_UOM], [t7].[IS_ACTIVE], [t7].[_ATTRIBUTES] AS [_ATTRIBUTES], [t7].[_DOCUMENTS] AS [_DOCUMENTS], [t7].[_SEO] AS [_SEO], [t7].[_TRANSLATIONS] AS [_TRANSLATIONS], [t7].[_TAGS] AS [_TAGS], [t7].[_NOTES] AS [_NOTES], [t7].[_METADATA] AS [_METADATA], [t7].[IS_B2B], [t7].[IS_B2C], [t7].[IS_PROMO], [t7].[IS_NEWS], [t7].[CAN_BE_RETURNED], [t7].[IS_SHIPPABLE], [t7].[HAS_SHIPPING_COSTS], [t7].[IS_PURCHEASABLE], [t7].[test], [t7].[ID2], [t7].[CODE2], [t7].[BUSINESS_NAME], [t7].[NAME], [t7].[PHONE_01], [t7].[PHONE_02], [t7].[PHONE_03], [t7].[FAX_01], [t7].[FAX_02], [t7].[COUNTRY_01], [t7].[CITY_01], [t7].[ADDRESS_01], [t7].[COUNTRY_02], [t7].[CITY_02], [t7].[ADDRESS_02], [t7].[EMAIL_01], [t7].[EMAIL_02], [t7].[PEC], [t7].[SITE_01], [t7].[SITE_02], [t7].[SITE_03], [t7].[SITE_04], [t7].[VAT_NUMBER], [t7].[SORT], [t7].[GROUPID_01], [t7].[IS_GROUPLEADER_01], [t7].[GROUPID_02], [t7].[IS_GROUPLEADER_02],[t7].[IS_ACTIVE2], [t7].[[_DOCUMENTS]]2] AS [_DOCUMENTS2], [t7].[[_SEO]]2] AS [_SEO2], [t7].[[_METADATA]]2] AS [_METADATA2], [t7].[test2], [t7].[ID3], [t7].[CODE3], [t7].[[_TRANSLATIONS]]2] AS [_TRANSLATIONS2], [t7].[[_METADATA]]3] AS [_METADATA3], [t7].[test3], [t7].[ID4], [t7].[ID_LINE], [t7].[ID_GROUP], [t7].[ID_CLASS], [t7].[ID_FAM], [t7].[ID_ARTICLE]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[ID], [t0].[ID_BRAND], [t0].[CODE], [t0].[CODFOR], [t0].[COD_ALT01], [t0].[COD_ALT02], [t0].[COD_ALT03], [t0].[ID_UOM], [t0].[IS_ACTIVE], [t0].[_ATTRIBUTES], [t0].[_DOCUMENTS], [t0].[_SEO], [t0].[_TRANSLATIONS], [t0].[_TAGS], [t0].[_NOTES], [t0].[_METADATA], [t0].[IS_B2B], [t0].[IS_B2C], [t0].[IS_PROMO], [t0].[IS_NEWS], [t0].[CAN_BE_RETURNED], [t0].[IS_SHIPPABLE], [t0].[HAS_SHIPPING_COSTS], [t0].[IS_PURCHEASABLE], [t2].[test], [t2].[ID], [t2].[CODE], [t2].[BUSINESS_NAME], [t2].[NAME], [t2].[PHONE_01], [t2].[PHONE_02], [t2].[PHONE_03], [t2].[FAX_01], [t2].[FAX_02], [t2].[COUNTRY_01], [t2].[CITY_01], [t2].[ADDRESS_01], [t2].[COUNTRY_02], [t2].[CITY_02], [t2].[ADDRESS_02], [t2].[EMAIL_01], [t2].[EMAIL_02], [t2].[PEC], [t2].[SITE_01], [t2].[SITE_02], [t2].[SITE_03], [t2].[SITE_04], [t2].[VAT_NUMBER], [t2].[SORT], [t2].[GROUPID_01], [t2].[IS_GROUPLEADER_01], [t2].[GROUPID_02], [t2].[IS_GROUPLEADER_02], [t2].[IS_ACTIVE], [t2].[_DOCUMENTS], [t2].[_SEO], [t2].[_METADATA], [t4].[test], [t4].[ID], [t4].[CODE], [t4].[_TRANSLATIONS], [t4].[_METADATA], [t6].[test], [t6].[ID], [t6].[ID_LINE], [t6].[ID_GROUP], [t6].[ID_CLASS], [t6].[ID_FAM], [t6].[ID_ARTICLE]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[ID], [t0].[ID_BRAND], [t0].[CODE], [t0].[CODFOR], [t0].[COD_ALT01], [t0].[COD_ALT02], [t0].[COD_ALT03], [t0].[ID_UOM], [t0].[IS_ACTIVE], [t0].[_ATTRIBUTES], [t0].[_DOCUMENTS], [t0].[_SEO], [t0].[_TRANSLATIONS], [t0].[_TAGS], [t0].[_NOTES], [t0].[_METADATA], [t0].[IS_B2B], [t0].[IS_B2C], [t0].[IS_PROMO], [t0].[IS_NEWS], [t0].[CAN_BE_RETURNED], [t0].[IS_SHIPPABLE], [t0].[HAS_SHIPPING_COSTS], [t0].[IS_PURCHEASABLE], [t2].[test], [t2].[ID] AS [ID2], [t2].[CODE] AS [CODE2], [t2].[BUSINESS_NAME], [t2].[NAME], [t2].[PHONE_01], [t2].[PHONE_02], [t2].[PHONE_03], [t2].[FAX_01], [t2].[FAX_02], [t2].[COUNTRY_01], [t2].[CITY_01], [t2].[ADDRESS_01], [t2].[COUNTRY_02], [t2].[CITY_02], [t2].[ADDRESS_02], [t2].[EMAIL_01], [t2].[EMAIL_02], [t2].[PEC], [t2].[SITE_01], [t2].[SITE_02], [t2].[SITE_03], [t2].[SITE_04], [t2].[VAT_NUMBER], [t2].[SORT], [t2].[GROUPID_01], [t2].[IS_GROUPLEADER_01], [t2].[GROUPID_02], [t2].[IS_GROUPLEADER_02], [t2].[IS_ACTIVE] AS [IS_ACTIVE2], [t2].[_DOCUMENTS] AS [[_DOCUMENTS]]2], [t2].[_SEO] AS [[_SEO]]2], [t2].[_METADATA] AS [[_METADATA]]2], [t4].[test] AS [test2], [t4].[ID] AS [ID3], [t4].[CODE] AS [CODE3], [t4].[_TRANSLATIONS] AS [[_TRANSLATIONS]]2], [t4].[_METADATA] AS [[_METADATA]]3], [t6].[test] AS [test3], [t6].[ID] AS [ID4], [t6].[ID_LINE], [t6].[ID_GROUP], [t6].[ID_CLASS], [t6].[ID_FAM], [t6].[ID_ARTICLE]
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_ana_Articles] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[ID], [t1].[CODE], [t1].[BUSINESS_NAME], [t1].[NAME], [t1].[PHONE_01], [t1].[PHONE_02], [t1].[PHONE_03], [t1].[FAX_01], [t1].[FAX_02], [t1].[COUNTRY_01], [t1].[CITY_01], [t1].[ADDRESS_01], [t1].[COUNTRY_02], [t1].[CITY_02], [t1].[ADDRESS_02], [t1].[EMAIL_01], [t1].[EMAIL_02], [t1].[PEC], [t1].[SITE_01], [t1].[SITE_02], [t1].[SITE_03], [t1].[SITE_04], [t1].[VAT_NUMBER], [t1].[SORT], [t1].[GROUPID_01], [t1].[IS_GROUPLEADER_01], [t1].[GROUPID_02], [t1].[IS_GROUPLEADER_02], [t1].[IS_ACTIVE], [t1].[_DOCUMENTS], [t1].[_SEO], [t1].[_METADATA]
        FROM [dbo].[tbl_ana_Brands] AS [t1]
        ) AS [t2] ON [t2].[ID] = [t0].[ID_BRAND]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS [test], [t3].[ID], [t3].[CODE], [t3].[_TRANSLATIONS], [t3].[_METADATA]
        FROM [dbo].[tbl_ana_UoMs] AS [t3]
        ) AS [t4] ON [t4].[ID] = [t0].[ID_UOM]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS [test], [t5].[ID], [t5].[ID_LINE], [t5].[ID_GROUP], [t5].[ID_CLASS], [t5].[ID_FAM], [t5].[ID_ARTICLE]
        FROM [dbo].[tbl_src_ArticlesCategories] AS [t5]
        ) AS [t6] ON [t6].[ID_ARTICLE] = [t0].[ID]
    WHERE (
        (CASE 
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN CONVERT(Int,[t0].[IS_ACTIVE])
            ELSE 0
         END)) = 1
    ) AS [t7]
WHERE [t7].[ROW_NUMBER]  BETWEEN 7272 + 1 AND 7284
ORDER BY [t7].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

Here slow query execution plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk-rLnY3F

Revised fast query (dataset of ~7K elements, take ~0s) :

```
SELECT [t7].[ID], [t7].[ID_BRAND], [t7].[CODE], [t7].[CODFOR], [t7].[COD_ALT01], [t7].[COD_ALT02], [t7].[COD_ALT03], [t7].[ID_UOM], [t7].[IS_ACTIVE], [t7].[_ATTRIBUTES] AS [_ATTRIBUTES], [t7].[_DOCUMENTS] AS [_DOCUMENTS], [t7].[_SEO] AS [_SEO], [t7].[_TRANSLATIONS] AS [_TRANSLATIONS], [t7].[_TAGS] AS [_TAGS], [t7].[_NOTES] AS [_NOTES], [t7].[_METADATA] AS [_METADATA], [t7].[IS_B2B], [t7].[IS_B2C], [t7].[IS_PROMO], [t7].[IS_NEWS], [t7].[CAN_BE_RETURNED], [t7].[IS_SHIPPABLE], [t7].[HAS_SHIPPING_COSTS], [t7].[IS_PURCHEASABLE], [t7].[test], [t7].[ID2], [t7].[CODE2], [t7].[BUSINESS_NAME], [t7].[NAME], [t7].[PHONE_01], [t7].[PHONE_02], [t7].[PHONE_03], [t7].[FAX_01], [t7].[FAX_02], [t7].[COUNTRY_01], [t7].[CITY_01], [t7].[ADDRESS_01], [t7].[COUNTRY_02], [t7].[CITY_02], [t7].[ADDRESS_02], [t7].[EMAIL_01], [t7].[EMAIL_02], [t7].[PEC], [t7].[SITE_01], [t7].[SITE_02], [t7].[SITE_03], [t7].[SITE_04], [t7].[VAT_NUMBER], [t7].[SORT], [t7].[GROUPID_01], [t7].[IS_GROUPLEADER_01], [t7].[GROUPID_02], [t7].[IS_GROUPLEADER_02],[t7].[IS_ACTIVE2], [t7].[[_DOCUMENTS]]2] AS [_DOCUMENTS2], [t7].[[_SEO]]2] AS [_SEO2], [t7].[[_METADATA]]2] AS [_METADATA2], [t7].[test2], [t7].[ID3], [t7].[CODE3], [t7].[[_TRANSLATIONS]]2] AS [_TRANSLATIONS2], [t7].[[_METADATA]]3] AS [_METADATA3], [t7].[test3], [t7].[ID4], [t7].[ID_LINE], [t7].[ID_GROUP], [t7].[ID_CLASS], [t7].[ID_FAM], [t7].[ID_ARTICLE]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[ID]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[ID], [t0].[ID_BRAND], [t0].[CODE], [t0].[CODFOR], [t0].[COD_ALT01], [t0].[COD_ALT02], [t0].[COD_ALT03], [t0].[ID_UOM], [t0].[IS_ACTIVE], [t0].[_ATTRIBUTES], [t0].[_DOCUMENTS], [t0].[_SEO], [t0].[_TRANSLATIONS], [t0].[_TAGS], [t0].[_NOTES], [t0].[_METADATA], [t0].[IS_B2B], [t0].[IS_B2C], [t0].[IS_PROMO], [t0].[IS_NEWS], [t0].[CAN_BE_RETURNED], [t0].[IS_SHIPPABLE], [t0].[HAS_SHIPPING_COSTS], [t0].[IS_PURCHEASABLE], [t2].[test], [t2].[ID] AS [ID2], [t2].[CODE] AS [CODE2], [t2].[BUSINESS_NAME], [t2].[NAME], [t2].[PHONE_01], [t2].[PHONE_02], [t2].[PHONE_03], [t2].[FAX_01], [t2].[FAX_02], [t2].[COUNTRY_01], [t2].[CITY_01], [t2].[ADDRESS_01], [t2].[COUNTRY_02], [t2].[CITY_02], [t2].[ADDRESS_02], [t2].[EMAIL_01], [t2].[EMAIL_02], [t2].[PEC], [t2].[SITE_01], [t2].[SITE_02], [t2].[SITE_03], [t2].[SITE_04], [t2].[VAT_NUMBER], [t2].[SORT], [t2].[GROUPID_01], [t2].[IS_GROUPLEADER_01], [t2].[GROUPID_02], [t2].[IS_GROUPLEADER_02], [t2].[IS_ACTIVE] AS [IS_ACTIVE2], [t2].[_DOCUMENTS] AS [[_DOCUMENTS]]2], [t2].[_SEO] AS [[_SEO]]2], [t2].[_METADATA] AS [[_METADATA]]2], [t4].[test] AS [test2], [t4].[ID] AS [ID3], [t4].[CODE] AS [CODE3], [t4].[_TRANSLATIONS] AS [[_TRANSLATIONS]]2], [t4].[_METADATA] AS [[_METADATA]]3], [t6].[test] AS [test3], [t6].[ID] AS [ID4], [t6].[ID_LINE], [t6].[ID_GROUP], [t6].[ID_CLASS], [t6].[ID_FAM], [t6].[ID_ARTICLE]
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_ana_Articles] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[ID], [t1].[CODE], [t1].[BUSINESS_NAME], [t1].[NAME], [t1].[PHONE_01], [t1].[PHONE_02], [t1].[PHONE_03], [t1].[FAX_01], [t1].[FAX_02], [t1].[COUNTRY_01], [t1].[CITY_01], [t1].[ADDRESS_01], [t1].[COUNTRY_02], [t1].[CITY_02], [t1].[ADDRESS_02], [t1].[EMAIL_01], [t1].[EMAIL_02], [t1].[PEC], [t1].[SITE_01], [t1].[SITE_02], [t1].[SITE_03], [t1].[SITE_04], [t1].[VAT_NUMBER], [t1].[SORT], [t1].[GROUPID_01], [t1].[IS_GROUPLEADER_01], [t1].[GROUPID_02], [t1].[IS_GROUPLEADER_02], [t1].[IS_ACTIVE], [t1].[_DOCUMENTS], [t1].[_SEO], [t1].[_METADATA]
        FROM [dbo].[tbl_ana_Brands] AS [t1]
        ) AS [t2] ON [t2].[ID] = [t0].[ID_BRAND]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS [test], [t3].[ID], [t3].[CODE], [t3].[_TRANSLATIONS], [t3].[_METADATA]
        FROM [dbo].[tbl_ana_UoMs] AS [t3]
        ) AS [t4] ON [t4].[ID] = [t0].[ID_UOM]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS [test], [t5].[ID], [t5].[ID_LINE], [t5].[ID_GROUP], [t5].[ID_CLASS], [t5].[ID_FAM], [t5].[ID_ARTICLE]
        FROM [dbo].[tbl_src_ArticlesCategories] AS [t5]
        ) AS [t6] ON [t6].[ID_ARTICLE] = [t0].[ID]
    WHERE (
        (CASE 
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN CONVERT(Int,[t0].[IS_ACTIVE])
            ELSE 0
         END)) = 1
    ) AS [t7]
WHERE [t7].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN 7272 + 1 AND 7284
ORDER BY [t7].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

Here the fast query exectution plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B10l82K2Y

Note : all the query code is autogenerated by ORM

The two queries look very similar, and is not clear to me what improve so drammatically the performance. I really appreciate an hint in what help SQL Server so much, so that i can better understand how to tune ORM in future.

Comment: `(CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN CONVERT(Int,[t0].[IS_ACTIVE]) ELSE 0 END)) = 1` could be optimized, you probably need to do something like `IsActive == true` rather than `IsActive == 1` in your client code

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the hint, it turned out that i have used a ternary condition inside the query, checking the variable returnOnlyActive, instead of use that variable to build the query (a version with is_active = true and a version without is_active). Big bulnder, i haven't noticed only now, maybe because i write it lot of year ago (mistake of youth :) )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### das spool

The main difference between the two queries is the presence of an [Eager Index Spool](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/starting-sql/starting-sql-eager-index-spools/).

From the article:

> Eager index spools can occur on the inner side of Nested Loops joins
> to reduce the amount of work that needs to be done there, by creating
> a more opportune index for the loop to work off of.
>
> That all sounds very good, but there are some problems:
>
> - The index gets created single-threaded
> - The way data is loaded into the spool is very inefficient
> - The spool is disposed of when the query is finished, It’ll get built over and over again on later executions
> - There’s no missing index request for the spool anywhere

But in your case, since the spool is quite small, it works in your favor.

### slowpoke

In the slow query, you have a nested loops join against `tbl_src_ArticlesCategories` which executes ~7k times, but doesn't have a useful index, so the entire table is scanned for each execution.

The scan:

[image: NUTS]

The details:

[image: NUTS]

You end up reading ~53 million rows in total when all is said and done, because you scan ~736k rows ~7k times.

### fastpoke

In the fast plan, you get this instead:

The scan and spool (with seek):

[image: NUTS]

The details

[image: NUTS]

The optimizer for this plan decided to create a good index for you, so it has a more suitable structure to use to locate matching rows in `ID_ARTICLE`.

You do ~7k seeks, which is much more efficient given the circumstances.

### equalizer

You could potentially get equal performance from both queries by adding this index:

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE?*/ INDEX spool_b_gone
    ON [dbo].[tbl_src_ArticlesCategories]
(
    [ID_ARTICLE]
)
INCLUDE
(
    [ID_LINE],
    [ID_GROUP], 
    [ID_CLASS], 
    [ID_FAM]
);
```

Though sometimes the optimizer is foolish and [may decide to spool](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/index-spools-when-you-have-an-index/) even when you have the right index in place.

### differences?

The immediate difference that I see is that in the slower execution, you generate the row number over a ton more columns across different tables:

[image: NUTS]

But I'm a bit short on time, so there may be other things contributing to the choice between spool/no spool.